# Is it possible to ignore sub-directories and files when removing interactively using `rm -ri <dir>`?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, gnu

> Is it possible to ignore sub-directories and files when removing interactively using `rm -ri <dir>`?

I want to interactively remove directories/files specified on the command-line, especially when using wildcards, e.g. `*`.

Now, since I want to remove directories, I need to specify `-r`, but this has the side-effect of making `rm` ask before deleting every directory/file in the top-level directory (`GhidraTest.rep`) recursively:

```
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ rm -ri GhidraTest.rep
examine files in directory GhidraTest.rep? y
examine files in directory GhidraTest.rep/versioned? y
remove GhidraTest.rep/versioned/~index.bak? y
remove GhidraTest.rep/versioned/~index.dat? y
remove GhidraTest.rep/versioned? y
examine files in directory GhidraTest.rep/idata?
```

Is it possible to make `rm` only ask for deleting top-level directories/files using `rm -ri`?

Comment: Use `I` instead of `i`, that is `rm -rI <directory>`.

Comment: @SantaXL - my `rm` doesn't have that option.

Comment: @Shuzheng but `-I` is available on debian 9 or debian 10. What is your debian version? [rm on debian 9](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/coreutils/rm.1) [rm on debian 10](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/coreutils/rm.1). Also available on debian 7 or 8.